# macbook pro google earth crashes on load, have never been able to use google earth

Tags: macos, osx-elcapitan, google-earth

for over  year now i have never been able to use google earth on this mac. as soon as google earth loads up it crashes....

OSX El Capital v 10.11.4
macbook pro retina 15 inch mid 2014
2.5ghz intel core i7
16gb 1600 mhz ddr3
nvidia geforce gt 750m 2048 mb

applicable part of the crash report is thread 0...

```
Process:               Google Earth [41056]
Path:                  /Applications/Google Earth.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Earth
Identifier:            com.Google.GoogleEarthPlus
Version:               7.1 (7.1.5.1557)
Code Type:             X86 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Google Earth [41056]
User ID:               501


Date/Time:             2016-04-10 16:18:18.838 -0700
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.4 (15E65)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        1504F42B-E3E3-6AC4-511B-68A2A53D901F


Sleep/Wake UUID:       435353B3-973A-430D-8186-3DD791EB15B5


Time Awake Since Boot: 320000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       1400 seconds


System Integrity Protection: enabled


Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread


Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes:       KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000000002d998a
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY


VM Regions Near 0x2d998a:
__LINKEDIT             0000000000005000-0000000000006000 [    4K] r--/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Google Earth.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Earth
--> __TEXT                 0000000000006000-0000000002112000 [ 33.0M] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Google Earth.app/Contents/Frameworks/libgoogleearth_free.dylib
__DATA                 0000000002112000-00000000021ec000 [  872K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Google Earth.app/Contents/Frameworks/libgoogleearth_free.dylib


Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   QtCore                         0x024d633d QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents(QObject*, int, QThreadData*) + 493
1   QtGui                         0x026c615f QDesktopWidget::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent*) + 8543
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x9a73724f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x9a714b9b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 523
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x9a713fc2 __CFRunLoopRun + 994
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x9a713976 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 390
6   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x9a7137db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
7   com.apple.HIToolbox           0x9e61f2f1 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 267
8   com.apple.HIToolbox           0x9e61efc5 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 201
9   com.apple.HIToolbox           0x9e61eeec _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 99
10  com.apple.AppKit               0x938a444e _DPSNextEvent + 1053
11  com.apple.AppKit               0x938a39c7 -[NSApplication _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1057
12  com.apple.AppKit               0x938a359e -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 121
13  com.apple.AppKit               0x93896cb3 -[NSApplication run] + 1063
14  QtGui                         0x026c747a QDesktopWidget::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent*) + 13434
15  QtCore                         0x024d1d31 QEventLoop::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 65
16  QtCore                         0x024d20fa QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 330
17  QtCore                         0x024d6800 QCoreApplication::exec() + 176
18  libgoogleearth_free.dylib     0x000896ba 0x6000 + 538298
19  libgoogleearth_free.dylib     0x00047551 mainMac + 777
20  com.Google.GoogleEarthPlus     0x00002c37 0x1000 + 7223
21  com.Google.GoogleEarthPlus     0x00002775 start + 53
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a known issue with cached files, a corrupt `myplaces.kml` file, or a graphics card that might need updating (unlikely with a MacBook Pro). In any case, Google has a step-by-step troubleshooting guide here:

[Google Earth Help: Resolving Crashing and Graphics Issues on a Mac](https://support.google.com/earth/answer/176181?hl=en)

You may also find the following discussion thread useful. It talks about compatibility issues between certain plugins - specially the `fbplugin` - which caused a lot of people to experience crashes on startup:

[Google Earth crashes on startup](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/8A6mgYBn7ik/discussion)

Answer (score 0):

Removed S7PWebVideoPugin.plugin and it works

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem but it was my add blocker. I disable the add blocker and it was fixed. For what it's worth.